# Excel - copy Data from multiple columns and rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So I have an excel sheet wtih data in columns currently but each column is a collection of 5 rows that need to stay together;

```
Column 1  Column 2
   a1        b1  
   a2        b2 
   a3        b3
```

And I want to lay it out as this

```
Column 1
  a1
  a2
  a3
  b1
  b2
  b3
 .... etc
```

I've tried various ways of transposing while pasting, and also tried doing a formula downwards which took the first 3 rows of column a, then column b but when I tried to copy it down to the next rows it just repeated a then b over and over again.

Comment: you actually need to unpivot your data. Search for that, there are a lot of suggestions on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Pick a cell outside the range of the table and enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROWS($2:2)-1,5),ROUNDUP(ROWS($2:2)/5,0)-1,)
```

and copy down:

[image]

***NOTE:***

Any table can be mapped into a single row or a single column and the mapping can be in either row order or column order.

Comment: Beautiful thank you - I don't know exactly what it's doing, but it works :)